# Change plotting range of facet when scales="free" and space="free"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote the following code to create what is essentially a broken x axis using facets. It was working great with ggplot version 2.2.1 and R version 3.4.3. When I upgraded to ggplot version 3.0.0, R version 3.5.1, the plotting range of the second facet renders it and its label unreadable. Is there any way to specify the plotting range so I can see the data?  Shouldn't the facet be at least as wide as the facet label? Is this bug?

```
library(ggplot2)

dd <- data.frame(hours = c(.1, .3, 1, 1.5, 6, 8, 24), 
                 Estimate = c(0.35, -3.6, -2.5, 0.7, -4, -6, -4.4), 
                 low = c(-4.3, -8.2, -7.2, -4.2, -8.6, -10.1, -9),
                 high = c(5.7, 1.0, 2.2, 5.6, 0.6, -.77, 0.17),
                 Day = c(rep("Day 1", 6), "Day 2" ))

makeplot <- function(x){
ggplot(data=x,
       aes(x=hours, y=Estimate,group=1))+ 
  facet_grid(~Day,scales="free",space="free") +
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_line(size=.9) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=hours, xend=hours,y=low,yend=high),size=1) +
  ylab(label=expression(paste("Change in y \n a versus b"))) +
  xlab(label="Hours elapsed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="grey") +
  ggtitle(paste0("Effect of x on y")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0:24)) +
  theme_bw(30) + 
  theme(legend.key.size=unit(.5, "inches"),
        line=element_line(size=2),
        panel.border=element_rect(size=2),
        panel.grid=element_line(size=1),
        axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=0),
        axis.title.y=element_text(hjust=0,margin = margin(l = 0)),
        legend.title=element_text(vjust=0),
        legend.text.align=0,
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,2), "cm"))
}

makeplot(dd)
```

ggplot version 2.2.1, R version 3.4.3:
[image]

ggplot version 3.0.0, R version 3.5.1:
[image]

Comment: Ok it seems it's specifically the difference between R 3.4.3 and R 3.5.1 that is causing this. That is, using R 3.4.3 with either ggplot2 version 2.2.1 or 3.0.0 seems to produce the first, more aesthetically pleasing plot.

Comment: If your comment could be added to the body of the question it might help. If this means you have figured out the problem entirely, then you should either delete or post an "answer" yourself if you think this is a useful observation.

Comment: I'm on R 3.4.1 & ggplot2 3.0.0. Using your code produces the 2nd chart, so I doubt it's R 3.5.1 that's directly responsible. Your 1st chart looks like it had additive expansion rather than multiplicative expansion. I can mimic its look on my machine if I add `expand = c(0, 0.5)` to `scale_x_continuous()`. Would that work for you?

Comment: Ok you're right--I am unable to reproduce this on a different machine. I have no idea why it was creating the plot that I wanted on that specific machine on that specific installation. It seems like the second plot is the intended default behavior and the first plot is actually some sort of ghost bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't actually reproduce the correctly spaced plot in 3.4.3 on another machine using this code, but Z.lin's solution works. axis breaks also need to be specified

```
... + scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:24,expand = c(0, 0.5))
```